# RuntimeError: expected scalar type Double but found Float pytorch lightning LSTM

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

Below is the error I am getting for an LSTM model in PyTorch even though they are all of the same datatype. The objective is to predict the value given a set of 4 values as the time window

Please find the code below:

```
class VDataset(Dataset):

def __init__(self, sequences):
    self.sequences = sequences
    
def __len__(self):
    return len(self.sequences)

def __getitem__(self, idx):
    sequence, label = self.sequences[idx]
    return dict(
            sequence = torch.tensor(sequence.to_numpy().astype(float)),
            label=torch.tensor(label).float()
    )

class VDataset_Loader(pl.LightningDataModule):
def __init__(self, train_sequences, test_sequences, batch_size = 8):
    super().__init__()
    self.train_sequences = train_sequences
    self.test_sequences = test_sequences
    self.batch_size = batch_size
def setup(self, stage=None):
    self.train_dataset = VDataset(self.train_sequences)
    self.test_dataset = VDataset(self.test_sequences)
def train_dataloader(self):
    return DataLoader(
        self.train_dataset,
        batch_size=self.batch_size,
        shuffle=False
    )
def test_dataloader(self):
    return DataLoader(
        self.test_dataset,
        batch_size=self.batch_size,
        shuffle=False
    )

class PredictionModel(nn.Module):
def __init__(self, n_features, n_hidden=128, n_layers=2):
    super().__init__()
    self.n_hidden = n_hidden
    self.lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size = n_features, hidden_size = n_hidden, batch_first=True,
                        num_layers = n_layers, dropout=0.2)
    self.regressor = nn.Linear(n_hidden, 1)

def forward(self, x):
    self.lstm.flatten_parameters()
    _, (hidden, _) = self.lstm(x)
    out = hidden[-1]
    return self.regressor(out)



class PredictionModelTraining(pl.LightningModule):
def __init__(self, n_features):
    super().__init__()
    self.model = PredictionModel(n_features)
    self.criterion = nn.MSELoss()
def forward(self, x, labels=None):
    output = self.model(x).float()
    loss = 0
    if labels is not None:
        loss = self.criterion(output, labels.unsqueeze(dim=1))
    return loss, output
def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
    sequences = batch['sequence']
    labels = batch['label']
    loss, output = self(sequences, labels)
    return loss
def test_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
    sequences = batch['sequence']
    labels = batch['label']
    loss, output = self(sequences, labels)
    return loss
def configure_optimizers(self):
    return optim.AdamW(self.parameters(), lr = 0.0001)
```

I am getting type error even though when I checked my tensor or iterate over the tensor, i could see float type for all tensors in it. Sorry for the alignment issue below the class declaration

Comment: Please add the full traceback